# What does there now mean here? "There now! What did I tell you?"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What does there now mean here?

> "There now! What did I tell you?"

And when can I use it like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there (definition 5).

'There' is used in various exclamations with no logical meaning, such as 'There, there' when trying to comfort a crying child. In your example it means 'See - it's happened just as I said it would!'.

Comment: I remember a [US TV "cop" series called McCloud](https://nostalgiacentral.com/television/tv-by-decade/tv-shows-1970s/mccloud/) from way back when. The main character was always saying ***There ya go**!* - usually as a kind of "resigned" exclamation lamenting some aspect of the current situation, but sometimes with the "confirmatory" sense of ***It's now obvious that I / you / he was correct.*** But the exclamation was always presented in such a way that the audience would be encouraged to *notice*, and ideally to think ***What a strange expression that is, when you stop to think about it!***